# How to fix NullPointerException in sites.html in AEM?

Tags: nullpointerexception, aem, internal-server-error

I'm suddenly getting `NullPointerException` in the `sites.html` link on the author in Adobe Experience Manager, Version 6.0.0.SP3

Any ideas? Please help.

```
Internal Server Error

Cannot serve request to /sites.html/content in /libs/cq/gui/components/siteadmin/admin/pagecard/pagecard.jsp

Exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.gui.components.siteadmin.admin.pagecard.pagecard_jsp.getCommentCount(pagecard_jsp.java:99)
...
```

[image]

Comment: The pagecard.jsp node has a jcr:content node and the permissions look correct. There are no deny rules. The administrators have been allowed jcr:all privilege at the root path. But even the administrators are getting the exception.

Answer (score 2):

We found **missing jcr:content** nodes for some pages **under /content**. 
Some existing jcr:content nodes were **missing jcr:title property**. 
We added the missing jcr:content nodes and jcr:title property. 
This solved the issue.

Note: 
The root of any of the sites (specifically sub-sites) should contain the following within their **jcr:content** – 
1. **Title** 
2. **cq:allowedTemplates** - to define the templates that go with this site specifically. 
3. **designPath** – which defines the clientlibs for the site and can contain options for the sidekick.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *crx-quickstart* folder in your file system and search for *pagecard_jsp.java*.

What is on line 99? I have a different version but I guess it is this line:

```
Resource commentsResource = page.getContentResource().getChild("alt/comments");
```

If this line throws a NPE, it means that one of the top-level pages under */content* is missing *jcr:content* node or the node is corrupted.

It is just a wild guessing without details.

Comment: Thank you Xinhang!

I see a different code on line 99
AttrBuilder attrs = tag.getAttrs();

I will check for the presence of jcr:content nodes for all pages.

Comment: I guess you were looking at the jsp file instead of the java file. But, anyway have a look at all jcr:content as I can replicate your issue. Please upvote.

Comment: You were right. We found missing jcr:content nodes for some pages under /content. We added those nodes. Some nodes were missing jcr:title property. We added this missing property too. This fixed the issue.

Note:
The root of any of the sites (specifically sub-sites) should contain the following within their jcr:content –
1. Title
2. cq:allowedTemplates - to define the templates that go with this site specifically. 
3. designPath – which defines the clientlibs for the site and can contain options for the sidekick.

Comment: I did upvote. I got the following message: 
Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to add the property under /content/your-folder/jcr:content as**:
**jcr:title** : give the exact name . Click on add and save all.